# Can I access the database file as a resource in Blackberry project?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

Can I access the database file as a local resource in Blackberry project via coding? Does not in SDCard storage!

Comment: I don't understand the question.   What database are you talking about?    "Does not in SDCard storage!" doesn't clarify anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is NO

but you can put your database in your resources folder and copy it to sdcard or eMMC and access it afterwards